# How to create folders and subfolders of the data present inside Excelsheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create folders using the content of the excel. I am able to read the excel file with the correct data but I am not able to create the folders from that data.

**The code which I have written so far:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\430427\\Desktop\\vivek.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {

            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            int i = 0;

            while (cells.hasNext()) {

                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                XSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(i);
                i++;
                if(cell2 !=null){
                //if(cell2.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "").length()>0)
                    System.out.print("/"+cell2);
                    String dirName = "C:\\Users\\430427\\Desktop\\"+cell2;
                    new File(dirName).mkdir();
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            i = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Lets try mkdirs(); instead of mkdir();

Comment: i tried mkdirs(); but the output is same only.I need nested folders but it is creating separate folders instead of nested.

Answer (score 1):

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html

cell2 is `XSSFCell` object not a string.

Try `cell2.getStringCellValue()`in `String dirName = "C:\\Users\\430427\\Desktop\\"+cell2;` to get the string value.

And I suggest you should get the user profile from your code instead of hardcoding the path.

---

**EDIT:**

There is no columnIterator in apache poi. So I came up with another approach.
This code will only make sense for your case (only one row at first columns & one or more rows at the last column) like you said in the comment:

> The data is like CALEG in A1,101 in B1,html in C1,Title A,Title
>   B,Title C,Title D in D1,D2,D3,D4 respectively.

I hope that give you some idea to implement what you needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;

        try {
            // input file path here    
            InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.xlsx");
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;
            Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

            // destination path here    
            String dirName = "D:\\tmp";
            String parentPath = null;

            int lastCellIdx = 0;

            while (rows.hasNext()) {

                row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

                if (lastCellIdx != 0) {

                    new File(parentPath + "\\" + row.getCell(lastCellIdx).toString()).mkdir();

                } else {

                    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cells.hasNext()) {
                        cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                        if (cell != null) {
                            dirName = dirName + "\\" + cell.toString();
                        }
                    }

                    lastCellIdx = row.getLastCellNum() - 1;
                    parentPath = new File(dirName).getParent();
                    new File(dirName).mkdirs();
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                wb.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i tried with cell2.getStringCellValue() also but the problem is not to get the cell value.The exact problem is i am not able to create nested folders from the data which is present in excel.

Comment: have u debugged and check cell2 contains data that you want? Can you show me how data in cell2 look like?

Comment: Yes i have checked..and cell2 is getting the same data of excel.

Comment: Is the data just a string without special characters? It must have thrown some kind of exception. Check the exception message.

Comment: data is just strings only..i am not able to paste the data over here..is there any other option for showing you that sample data..?

Comment: Are these data in separate cells like CALEG in A1, 101 in A2, etc? If so, in order to create nested folder, you need to save the dirName String of the previous path then create subfolder under dirName.

Comment: Or if all string are in same cell like "aa bb cc" and you want to create `C:\Users\430427\Desktop\aa\bb\cc`, replace spaces with "\" and use mkdirs instead. It will automatically create parent folders if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The data is like CALEG in A1,101 in B1,html in C1,Title A,Title B,Title C,Title D in D1,D2,D3,D4 respectively. you can put these data into excel sheet what i have mentioned.Now what i have to do is-i need to create a Parent folder CALEG then inside that 101 then inside it html and inside html there should be 4 folders of Title A,B,C,C..hope you got my point

Comment: Ya Its created now.Thanks...:)